# VHDL 4-bit Shift-and-Add Multiplier Buffer and Out port error

Tags: vhdl, shift-register, register, port, multiplier

I am working on a creating a 4-bit Shift-and-Add Multiplier. I am getting this warning message - 
"WARNING:HDLParsers:3555 - "//filer1.egr.msu.edu/samarar1/ece230/Project05/Project05.vhd" Line 220. Warning for LRM section 1.1.1.2 violation about connectivity rules. Parameter P of mode buffer should not be associated with a formal port of mode out."

How can I fix this warning? 
Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity shiftlne is
generic(n:integer:= 4);
port (R     :in     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
        L,E,w :in       STD_LOGIC;
        Clock   :in     STD_LOGIC;
        Q       :buffer STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0));
end shiftlne;

architecture Behavioral of shiftlne is
begin
process
begin
    wait until Clock'Event and Clock = '1';
    if L = '1' then
          Q <= R;
    elsif E = '1' then
        Q(0) <= w;
        Genbits: for i in 1 to n-1 loop
            Q(i) <= Q(i-1);
        End loop;
    End if;
End process;
end Behavioral;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity shiftrne is
generic(n:integer:= 4);
port(R  :in     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
     L,E,w:in       STD_LOGIC;
     Clock:in       STD_LOGIC;
     Q      :buffer  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0));
end shiftrne;

architecture Behavioral of shiftrne is
begin
process
begin
    wait until Clock'Event and Clock = '1';
    if E = '1' then
        if L = '1' then
            Q <= R;
        else
            Genbits: for i in 0 to n-2 loop
                Q(i) <= Q(i+1);
            end loop;
            Q(n-1) <= w;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
 end Behavioral;

 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

 entity mux2to1 is
port (w0,w1,s :in   STD_LOGIC;
        f         :out  STD_LOGIC);
 end mux2to1;
 architecture Behavioral of mux2to1 is
 begin
with s select
f <= w0 when '0',
      w1 when others;
 end Behavioral;

 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

 entity regne is
generic (n: integer:= 4);
port(R          :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
      Resetn        :in STD_LOGIC;
      E,Clock   :in STD_LOGIC;
      Q         :out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0));
 end regne;

 architecture Behavioral of regne is
 begin
process(Resetn,Clock)
begin
    if Resetn = '0' then
        Q <= (others => '0');
    elsif Clock'event and Clock = '1' then
        if E = '1' then
            Q <= R;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
 end Behavioral;

 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

 entity Multiplier is
generic (n:integer:=4; nn:integer:=8);
port (Clock     :in std_logic;
        Resetn  :in std_logic;
        LA,LB,s :in std_logic;
        DataA       :in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
        DataB       :in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
        P         :buffer std_logic_vector(nn-1   downto 0);
        Done        :out std_logic);
 end Multiplier;

 architecture Behavioral of Multiplier is
type state_type is (s1,s2,s3);
signal y: state_type;
signal Psel,z,EA,EB,EP,Zero: std_logic;
signal B,n_Zeros: std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
signal A,Ain,DataP,Sum: std_logic_vector(nn-1 downto 0);

component mux2to1
    port(w0,w1  :in STD_LOGIC;
          s     :in STD_LOGIC;
          f     :out STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component regne
    generic(n:integer:= 4);
    port(R          :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
          Resetn    :in STD_LOGIC;
          E,Clock   :in STD_LOGIC;
          Q     :out    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0));
end component;

component shiftlne
    generic(n:integer:= 4);
    port (R         :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
            L,E,w       :in     STD_LOGIC;
            Clock       :in STD_LOGIC;
            Q   :buffer STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0));
end component;

component shiftrne
    generic(n:integer:= 4);
    port (R         :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
            L,E,w       :in     STD_LOGIC;
            Clock       :in STD_LOGIC;
            Q   :buffer STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0));
end component;

 begin
FSM_transitions: process(Resetn,Clock)
begin
    if Resetn = '0' then
            y<=s1;
    elsif (Clock'event and Clock = '1') then
     case y is
          when s1=>
          if s = '0' then y <= s1; else y <= s2;                    
 end if;
        when s2=>
            if z = '0' then y <= s2; else y <= s3;      
 end if;
            when s3 =>
             if s = '1' then y <= s3; else y <= s1;      
 end if;
        end case;
    end if;
end process;

FSM_outputs: process(y,s,B(0))
begin
    EP <= '0'; EA <= '0'; EB <= '0'; Done <= '0'; Psel <= '0';
    case y is
        when s1 =>
            EP <= '1';
        when s2 =>
            EA <= '1'; EB <= '1'; Psel <= '1';
            if B(0) = '1' then EP <= '1'; else EP <= '0'; 
 end if;
        when s3 =>
            Done <= '1';
    end case;
end process;

Zero <= '0';
n_Zeros <= (others => '0');
Ain <= n_Zeros & DataA;
ShiftA:shiftlne generic map (n=>nn)
    port map(Ain,LA,EA,Zero,Clock,A);
ShiftB:shiftrne generic map (n=>n)
    port map(DataB,LB,EB,Zero,Clock,B);
z <= '1' when B = n_Zeros else '0';
Sum <= A + P;

GenMUX: for i in 0 to nn-1 generate
    Muxi: mux2to1 port map (Zero,Sum(i),Psel,DataP(i));
end generate;
RegP:regne generic map (n=>nn)
    port map (DataP,Resetn,EP,Clock,P);

 end Behavioral;
```

Comment: So that we don’t have to count 220 lines, maybe you could point out the line that the error is referring to?

Comment: Copy and pasted your code in a text editor. There is no line 220.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is where it goes wrong:
`RegP:regne generic map (n=>nn)
    port map (DataP,Resetn,EP,Clock,P);`

The port P is coming from is an output but P is a buffer.

I recommended to never use 'buffer' exactly for this reason. 
Use a local variable to read and write and assign that to an output.
I use the convention of adding _buf to that type of local signals in my design: output port is Q, local signal is Q_buf,  Q <= Q_buf.

For example: you have a big almost working design. For some reason you find that you have an output signal that you need to read back. Thus you change the port to 'buffer' and....your VHDL system falls apart! 
Now it wants you to change ALL ports in the hierarchy of all modules where that signal goes through from output to buffer.

Comment: It looks like our answers overlapped - and we highlighted the exact same thing. +1 for beating me to the punch.

Comment: Those things happen.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your problem is here:

> RegP:regne generic map (n=>nn)
>       port map (DataP,Resetn,EP,Clock,P); — <—- here

where you are trying to assign an output port `Q     :out    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0));` to a buffer. Buffers must have their values assigned internally, and typically can’t connect to `out`.

My advice is to minimize your use of buffers. They often lead to problems, especially in synthesis.